# The image is not shown, even I tried to take the image from html data table and to display it into a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can take the data from HTML data table to set it into textbox now I am trying to take the image from HTML data table and to set it into a div but the image doesn't come. any solution!

```
  //HTML code for image div
  <div class="down" id="imgS" >
  <a href="#" ><img src="images/IT.jpg"></a>
  </div>

 //HTML code for Id div 
 <div class="md-form mb-5" style="margin-left:130px;">
 <div class="input-group-prepend" >
 <span class="input-group-text">ID</span>
 </div>
 <input type="text" name="txtSId" id="txtSId" class="form-control">
 </div>

 //jQuery code
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dtBasicExample tbody").on('click','tr',function(){
  $("#txtSelect").text("1 row selected");    
  var rowData=$(this).children("td").map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  $("#txtSId").val(rowData[0]);
  $("#imgS").html("<a href='#'><img src=rowData[3]></a>");
  });    
  });
  </script>
```

Now it working for Id but I need to display my image which is not working!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#imgS").html("<a href='#'><img src='"+rowData[3]+"'></a>");//add single qoute src=''
```

I hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: No result! it's the same the image can't display

Comment: sir please check your data in console first by doing this console.log(rowData[3]); if this showing correct url or not, instead its showing undefined ? if this is showing correct url in console then above code should definitely work.

Comment: It provides like this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: rowData is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: then you need to get that correct data first. After you sure that you are getting proper image url in console then put in above code. above code should work perfectly

Comment: So how to take the correct data let me make it correct. all data is correct but just when I take the image from HTML data table is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
 $("#imgS").html("<a href='#'><img src=rowData[3]></a>");
```

to

```
 $("#imgS").html("<a href='#'><img src='"+rowData[3]+"'></a>");
```

Comment: No result! it's the same the image can't display

Comment: can you give me the result for `console.log(rowData);`

Comment: rowData is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not showing because the value in your `src` attibute is set to `rowData[3]` **not the content of `rowData[3]`**. You can use `+` operator to embed the expression with normal string as suggested by other answers

OR

use template literals `` (two back-ticks) as following

```
$("#imgS").html(`<a href="#"><img src="${rowData[3]}"></a>`);
```

For inserting Small string like this it is just a syntactic sugar but if you have more expression to interpolate and embed with normal strings or if your string spans multiple line then it is more convenient to use template literals.

```
$("#imgS").html(`<a href="#">
                  <img src="${rowData[3]}">
                </a>`);
```

This is still valid and more readable thanks to template literals

Comment: No result! it's the same the image can't display

Comment: What does rowData[3] gives?

Comment: Just it gives a div even it doesn't show image just a div nothing else